# Order of words in Lucene proximity search

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Is it possible to specify whether the order of words matters for a Lucene proximity search?

> "word1 word2"~3 => order of words does matter (InOrder = true)

is there an equivalent way to write a query for which the order doesn't matter? Something like:

> "word1 word2"~3x => order of words does not matter (InOrder = false)

I know that for a SpanNearQuery the InOrder property determines if the order matters or not but not how I am able to tell a QueryParser if InOrder should be true or false for a specific SpanNearQuery.

Would I need to write my own QueryParser for this that supports a custom Syntax to deal with such queries?

Answer (score 2):

You have it backward.  The `QueryParser` always sets `InOrder` to false.

`InOrder = false` does not, however, mean order *doesn't matter*.  It means order is not strictly maintained.  Order still matters, because the proximity value is a levenshtein distance.  Swapping two words' order increases the distance by 2.  You might see matches on the reversed order if you try increasing the distance by two.

As far as whether you can structure your query to set whether order should be maintained in the query parser:  No.  You can't.  It doesn't support that.

You could switch over to using the [Surround Query Parser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/surround/parser/QueryParser.html), which is designed to handle more complex span queries.  However, the syntax is *much* different, and I don't know whether a .Net version is out there.  It was around at Lucene 3.0.3, but it was a contrib package then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using a self-ported .net version of the ComplexPhraseQueryParser, in which InOrder is always true. That is why I assumed this would be the default behaviour of the QueryParser as well. Unfortunately it seems that Lucene.Net and also Lucene.Net.Contrib do not contain the surround package. So I guess I either have to wait till the new version of Lucene.Net is released or write somethling like the Surround QueryParser myself

Comment: I have just tested the InOrder property and the results indicate that for InOrder=false the order of the terms really does not matter:

"term1 term2" slop=0 InOrder=true results in 9 hits, 
"term2 term1" slop=0 InOrder=true results in 5 hits, 
"term1 term2" slop=0 InOrder=false results in 14 hits, 
"term2 term1" slop=0 InOrder=false results in 14 hits,

Or am I missing something?