# Lucene how can i make request without position?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a text:

```
Text[0]: word1
Text[1]: WAR
Text[2]: word2
Text[3]: FORCE
Text[4]: word3
Text[5]: OPERATION
Text[6]: word6
```

And i want to create query for rules:

1. words in any order
2. at a given distance from each other

When if i want to find "WAR FORCE OPERATION" with slop for example 1. And searcher have to find:

1)

```
Text[0]: word1
Text[1]: WAR
Text[2]: word2
Text[3]: FORCE
Text[4]: word3
Text[5]: OPERATION
Text[6]: word6
```

or 2:

```
Text[0]: word1
Text[1]: OPERATION
Text[2]: !slop=1!
Text[3]: WAR
Text[4]: !slop=1!
Text[5]: FORCE
Text[6]: word6
```

or something like that, find in any orders, but so that all 3 words are exactly in the text.

---

No thoughts how this can be done, please tell me how to make such a request?

---

New description:

For example: i want to find (abc) with slop = 1,

The rules will be:

```
a b c
a c b
b a c 
b c a 
c a b 
c b a
```

or x - other word

```
a x b x c
a x c x b
b x a x c 
b x c x a 
c x a x b 
c x b x a
```

abc - in any order. With parameter slop = 1 , this means that between words (a b c) there can be 0 or 1 word.
Wrong if

```
a x x b x x c
```

or

```
a x b x a
```

It is necessary that these 3 words are exactly in the text and at the same time be at the distance specified by the parameter slop.
And words in front of "a" are not important, and after "c":

```
x x x a x b x c x x x
```

Comment: The answers to these (and your other) questions are based on Lucene's [classic query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description).

Comment: So, for example: For words in any order: `word1 AND word2 AND word3 AND ...`. I may (again) be misunderstanding your question, but does that not work for you?

Comment: AND - such an operator is present at any distance, but it is important for me that it is still possible to set the distance.

Comment: I want 2 possibilities:
1) so that all words are exactly in the text, 2) so that they are at a given distance from each other

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I am still not entirely sure what you mean by "at a given distance from each other" - that could mean a couple of different things. I think we need more examples of what counts as a match and what does not, to help explain the question more clearly. For example, if the words to match are `A`, `B`, and `C`, which of the following will match what you want - and which will not match (and why)? `x A B C x`, `x C B A x`, `x A x B x C`, `x C x B x A x`, `x A x x x x x x B C`... and so on... Can you give us enough examples to make it clear what you need?

Comment: I add new details, what do u think about it?

Comment: Thank you for the updates, again - that helps. I think proximity queries are the wrong approach here, because these types of query are affected by word order, whereas your examples make it clear that you want to explicitly _not_ consider word order. You would need to chain together some complex proximity queries to handle your requirements, with many combinations of terms in different orders in the query, to handle this. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674596/order-of-words-in-lucene-proximity-search). Sorry, I do not know a good approach for what you need.